# Cast SDK issue: receiver is stuck in "playback stalled in buffered region"

Tags: google-cast

When playing HLS videos, the receiver often stay stuck with warnings "playback stalled in buffered region" (after ~10seconds of playback).

On a previous project, a workaround was to download the media_player.js, patch the code:

```
(this.Db = this.a.Ui ? b : null, F(Om, "playback stalled in buffered region"), za("Cast.MPL.PlaybackStall"), this.xe = this.Eg = !0, this.s.currentTime = a + .5)
```

to

```
(this.Db = this.a.Ui ? b : null, F(Om, "playback stalled in buffered region"), za("Cast.MPL.PlaybackStall"), this.xe = this.Eg = !0, this.s.currentTime = a + 0.5, this.s.currentTime = a + 0.5)
```

And then host this patched version of media_player.js on our server.

But this process is highly not recommended in the cast sdk documentation, and we do not want this for our new project.

So we expect that this will be fixed in the receiver sdk directly.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to figure it out?